# SQL How to add ID column into a Split select

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have the following query:

```
SELECT s FROM dbo.Split(',',(
select 
emp.Data
FROM Employee emp
WHERE EmployeeID = 56640
))
```

The Data column is a comma separated value:

```
emp.Data has the value: '461086,461104'
```

This returns the following table:

[image]

Now, I need to add to this select the `EmployeeID` column, so I need something like this

```
SELECT s FROM dbo.Split(',',(
select 
emp.EmployeeId,
emp.Data
FROM Employee emp
WHERE EmployeeID = 56640
))
```

But this give me an error.

Any clue?

Comment: how does your table withe empID look like?

Comment: It has 4 columns, PK is EmployeeID and last column is Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `cross apply`:

```
select emp.EmployeeId, s.val
FROM Employee emp CROSS APPLY
     dbo.split(',', emp.data) s(val)
WHERE emp.EmployeeID = 56640;
```